# Complete a string base on index of last character

Tags: c#, string

Example Word : String , the returned last index is 5 which is "g". I need to complete the word string base on the space before the word.

For example

obj string the last index is 5, which is g, "string" word should be completed.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Can you please show some examples of inputs and their associated outputs?

Comment: Welcome to OS, please see [how to ask](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question) good questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using C#, you can use [String.LastIndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1tw91fa3(v=vs.110).aspx) method to report the last occurrence of ' ' character then use [String.Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx) to extract the word.

For other languages, Google is your friend :)